# Help with an old (80's or 90's) science fiction movie with 2 time travelling kids?

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

From what I remember of the movie, there were these two "villains" in red and yellow suits that looked like something from power rangers. The kids ended up in a place/dimension that looked like a cave, that had this small person working there who was hostile to them at first, but they then made friends with it.

It was later revealed that the power suits were built by the little person, and the two villains were in fact older versions of the kids, the boy being in the red suit and the girl in the yellow. The "villains" were in fact just there to make the kids behave in a way that would lead to the future they were living in currently.  The kids grow up to marry each other.

The younger version of the girl kicked the red-suited older version of the boy in the groin when they were being chased, for which the older version of the girl apologised to the boy later on.

Comment: Did they time travel on a carousel?

Comment: @Valorum they might have done...apologies, I don't recall!

Comment: Relevant TVTropes link: [FutureSelfReveal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FutureSelfReveal)

Comment: When you say "little person", are you meaning it in the sense of "person with dwarfism"?

Comment: It would appear that this user on Movies:SE knew the answer. Unfortunately they didn't say what movie they were thinking of... https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/25110/time-travel-movie-with-a-spinning-time-machine#comment52886_25110

Comment: @Valorum That's the same user who asked this question.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - Ah, well no help there then :-) although that question does ask it they grew up and married. No mention of that above.

Comment: @Gokotai Was this film live-action or animated? Shown in a cinema, or direct-to-video, or a TV movie?

Comment: @Valorum indeed I do! they were speaking an alien language, if I recall and served a master who was killed by the two protaganists.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I saw it on tv as a movie, so it might have been direct-to-video or a tv movie. Considering how little success I've had in finding it, I think it's very unlikely to have been in cinemas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! It's a really obscure movie called [Backtime](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0189383/?ref_=tt_ch) (1996/8)

> A young couple is accidentally sent into the future, 7,000 years from now, when time terrorists steal from the present day, creating a paradox that threatens to destroy them, all.

Comment: The VFX on this are appalling :-)

Comment: @Valorum haha absolutely, looks terrible! But a guilty pleasure nontheless!

Comment: @Gokotai: You should mark your answer as correct to close the question.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen done, thank you!